# NGINX RTMP - HLS Variants has no video

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, nginx-config, rtmp, nginx-rtmp

I'm trying to get HLS Fragmentation to work using the NGINX-RTMP module. The livestream itself is working, its seems to just be an issue with the resolution changing. I'm also getting audio.

This is the rtmp section of my nginx.conf

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4096;

        application live {
            live on;

            allow publish all;
            allow play all;

            exec ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/$app/$name
                -c:v libaom-av1 -b:v 1400k -c:a aac -b:a 128k -vf "scale=384:216" -tune zerolatency -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/$name_bad
                -c:v libaom-av1 -b:v 2500k -c:a aac -b:a 128k -vf "scale=768:432" -tune zerolatency -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/$name_low
                -c:v libaom-av1 -b:v 6000k -c:a aac -b:a 144k -vf "scale=1280:720" -tune zerolatency -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/$name_mid
                -c:v libaom-av1 -b:v 10000k -c:a aac -b:a 144k -vf "scale=1920:1080" -tune zerolatency -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/$name_hi;
        }

        application hls {
            live on;

            allow publish all;
            allow play all;
            
            hls on;
            hls_path /tmp/hls/;
            hls_nested on;

            hls_variant _bad BANDWIDTH=1528000,RESOLUTION=384x216,NAME="216p",FRAME-RATE=30;
            hls_variant _low BANDWIDTH=2628000,RESOLUTION=768x432,NAME="432p",FRAME-RATE=30;
            hls_variant _mid BANDWIDTH=6144000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,NAME="720p60",FRAME-RATE=60;
            hls_variant _hi BANDWIDTH=10144000,RESOLUTION=1920x1080,NAME="1080p60",FRAME-RATE=60;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the stream.m3u8 generated by NGINX

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1528000,RESOLUTION=384x216,NAME="216p"
stream_bad/index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2628000,RESOLUTION=768x432,NAME="432p"
stream_low/index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=6144000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,NAME="720p60"
stream_mid/index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=10144000,RESOLUTION=1920x1080,NAME="1080p60"
stream_hi/index.m3u8
```

I've tried both switching from libaom-av1 to libx264 and removing the framerate changes and still got the same issue.

Thanks for your help!